# Filtering array of dictionaries in Swift

Tags: swift2, nsmutablearray, uisearchbar, nspredicate, nsmutabledictionary

I have An Array With Dictionaries example :

```
(
        {
        Email = "kate-bell@mac.com";
        Name = "Kate Bell";
        Number = "(555) 564-8583";
    },
        {
        Email = "d-higgins@mac.com";
        Name = "Daniel Higgins";
        Number = "555-478-7672";
    }
)
```

And i want to filter this dictionary according to Key "Name"

```
 func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format:"Name == %@", searchText)
    let filteredArray = (arrContact as NSMutableArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(predicate)
    print(filteredArray)
    if(filteredArray.count == 0){
                searchActive = false;
            } else {
                searchActive = true;
            }
            tblData.reloadData()
 }
```

I am always getting empty array in result from above swift code. Please help me to resolve this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 16):

I suggest using Swift's `filter` instead:

```
func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    let filteredArray = arrContact.filter { $0["Name"] == searchText }
    print(filteredArray)
    if filteredArray.isEmpty {
        searchActive = false
    } else {
        searchActive = true
    }
    tblData.reloadData()
}
```

And as mentioned by @LeoDabus in his comment, you can even simplify further:

```
func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    let filteredArray = arrContact.filter { $0["Name"] == searchText }
    print(filteredArray)
    searchActive = !filteredArray.isEmpty
    tblData.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: `searchActive = !filteredArray.isEmpty`

Answer (score 8):

**Try This for swift 3**

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    // Put your key in predicate that is "Name"
    let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "Name CONTAINS[C] %@", searchText)
    let array = (arrContact as NSArray).filtered(using: searchPredicate)

    print ("array = \(array)")

    if(array.count == 0){
        searchActive = false;
    } else {
        searchActive = true;
    }
    self.aTable.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: @Abhishek Rathore. please let me know if you have any issue

Comment: that was an awsome answer even i had the same issue but your answer saved my day

Comment: Not working in Swift 4. Please update or add for Swift 4

Answer (score 3):

**Swift**

Get list of item/array from model class.

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if self.searchBarItems.text == "" {
        self.arrFilter = self.arrayDictionarySubModel
    } else {
        self.arrFilter.removeAll()
        let filteredArray = self.arrayDictionarySubModel.filter { ($0.itemTitle?.contains(self.searchBarItems.text ?? ""))!}
        print("filtered array:- ", filteredArray[0].itemTitle!)
        self.arrFilter = filteredArray
    }
    self.searchItemTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

where "name" is the key name

```
  var namePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "Name like %@",  String(searchText));
        let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "Name CONTAINS[C] %@", searchText)
        arrrDict = self.arrrDict.filter { searchPredicate.evaluate(with: $0) };
       you will get the result in dictionary specialy made to get contats from the phone book
```