# UISearch is not Working in JSON api UITable View

Tags: ios, json, uisearchresultscontroller

All

I am trying to develop an app. Now i need to search the video list using UISearch View.

here is my code. I can see the search bar but it's not working.

import UIKit
import GoogleMobileAds

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, GADInterstitialDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet weak var tblVideos: UITableView!

@IBOutlet weak var banner3: GADBannerView!


var interstitial: GADInterstitial!


@IBOutlet weak var viewWait: UIView!



var channelsDataArray: Array<Dictionary<String, Any>> = []

var apikey = ""

var selectedVideoIndex: Int!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    if connectedToNetwork() == true {

        tblVideos.delegate = self
        tblVideos.dataSource = self

        print("Google Mobile Ads SDK version: " + GADRequest.sdkVersion())
        banner3.adUnitID = ""
        banner3.rootViewController = self
        banner3.load(GADRequest())

        getChannelDetails(false)
        loadInterstitial()
        searchBar()

    }

    else {
        let controller = UIAlertController(title: "No Internet Detected", message: "This app requires an Internet connection", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
        let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

        controller.addAction(ok)
        controller.addAction(cancel)

        present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func searchBar() {
    let searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 50))
    searchBar.delegate = self
    searchBar.showsScopeBar = true
    searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.lightGray
    self.tblVideos.tableHeaderView = searchBar

}


func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    if searchText == "" {
        //do something
        getChannelDetails(false)
    }
    else {

            channelsDataArray = channelsDataArray.filter({($0["title"] as! String).contains(searchText)})

    }

}


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let playerViewController = segue.destination as? PlayerViewController {
        playerViewController.videoID = channelsDataArray[selectedVideoIndex]["videoId"] as! String
    }
}




// MARK: UITableView method implementation

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return channelsDataArray.count


}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell: UITableViewCell!


    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "idCellChannel", for: indexPath)

    let channelTitleLabel = cell.viewWithTag(10) as! UILabel

    let thumbnailImageView = cell.viewWithTag(12) as! UIImageView

    let channelDetails = channelsDataArray[indexPath.row]
    channelTitleLabel.text = channelDetails["title"] as? String

    thumbnailImageView.image = UIImage(data: try! Data(contentsOf: URL(string: (channelDetails["url"] as? String)!)!))


    return cell
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 350.0
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    selectedVideoIndex = indexPath.row
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "idSeguePlayer", sender: self)
    if (interstitial!.isReady) {
        interstitial!.present(fromRootViewController: self)
    }
    loadInterstitial()

}







// MARK: UITextFieldDelegate method implementation



// MARK: Custom method implementation

func performGetRequest(_ targetURL: URL!, completion: @escaping (_ data: Data?, _ HTTPStatusCode: Int, _ error: Error?) -> Void) {
    var request = URLRequest(url: targetURL)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"

    let sessionConfiguration = URLSessionConfiguration.default

    let session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfiguration)

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) -> Void in
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
            completion(data, (response as! HTTPURLResponse).statusCode, error)
        })
    } )

    task.resume()
}


func getChannelDetails(_ useChannelIDParam: Bool) {
    var urlString: String!
    if !useChannelIDParam {
        urlString = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id%2Csnippet&type=video&q=mufti+amir+hamza&maxResults=50&key=apikey"
    }

    let targetURL = URL(string: urlString)

    performGetRequest(targetURL, completion: { (data, HTTPStatusCode, error) -> Void in
        if HTTPStatusCode == 200 && error == nil {

            do {

                if let resultsDict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [String:Any] {
                    if let items = resultsDict["items"] as? [[String:Any]] {
                        for item in items {
                            var desiredValues = [String:Any]()

                            //get the videoId
                            if let id = item["id"] as? [String:Any], let videoId = id["videoId"] as? String{
                                desiredValues["videoId"] = videoId
                            }

                            //get title and thumbnail from snippet
                            if let snippet = item["snippet"] as? [String:Any] {
                                if let title = snippet["title"] {
                                    desiredValues["title"] = title
                                }
                                if let thumbanail = snippet["thumbnails"] as? [String:Any], let highValues = thumbanail["high"] as? [String:Any], let url = highValues["url"] as? String {
                                    desiredValues["url"] = url
                                }
                            }
                            self.channelsDataArray.append(desiredValues)
                        }
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.tblVideos.reloadData()
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (let error){
                print("Error while parsing data: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }

        self.viewWait.isHidden = true

    })
}




//inter

fileprivate func loadInterstitial() {
    interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "")
    interstitial!.delegate = self

    // Request test ads on devices you specify. Your test device ID is printed to the console when
    // an ad request is made.
    interstitial!.load(GADRequest())
}


// MARK: GADInterstitialDelegate implementation

func interstitialDidFailToReceiveAdWithError (
    _ interstitial: GADInterstitial,
    error: GADRequestError) {
    print("interstitialDidFailToReceiveAdWithError: %@" + error.localizedDescription)
}

func interstitialDidDismissScreen (_ interstitial: GADInterstitial) {
    print("interstitialDidDismissScreen")

}
```

}

I just need to now filter my list as a Titile. Can please any help me to solved it?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36496791/filtering-array-of-dictionaries-in-swift) might help

Comment: Is your searcBar(_:didChange:) methods being called when you enter text in search bar?

Comment: @user1000 yes it's called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need declare a var for filteredArray to keep your original array with all your elements

something like this

```
var filteredChannelsDataArray : Array<Dictionary<String, Any>> = []
```

You also need add this line after `self.channelsDataArray.append(desiredValues)` in your `getChannelDetails` method

```
self.filteredChannelsDataArray = channelsDataArray
```

Try with this

**Replace this**

```
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    if searchText == "" {
        //do something
        getChannelDetails(false)
    }
    else {

         channelsDataArray = channelsDataArray.filter({ (alldata) -> Bool in

        return true

    })

    }

}
```

**By this**

```
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    if searchText == "" {
        //do something
        getChannelDetails(false)
        self.filteredChannelsDataArray = channelsDataArray
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
    else {

            self.filteredChannelsDataArray = channelsDataArray.filter({($0["title"] as! String).contains(searchText)})
           self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

}
```

**You also need make few changes in your `UITableViewDataSource` methods**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.filteredChannelsDataArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell: UITableViewCell!


    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "idCellChannel", for: indexPath)

    let channelTitleLabel = cell.viewWithTag(10) as! UILabel

    let thumbnailImageView = cell.viewWithTag(12) as! UIImageView

    let channelDetails = self.filteredChannelsDataArray[indexPath.row]
    channelTitleLabel.text = channelDetails["title"] as? String

    thumbnailImageView.image = UIImage(data: try! Data(contentsOf: URL(string: (channelDetails["url"] as? String)!)!))


    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try with this code : self.tblVideos.reloadData()

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
     if searchText == "" {
         //do something
         getChannelDetails(false)
     }
     else {

        channelsDataArray = channelsDataArray.filter({($0["title"] as! String).contains(searchText)})
        self.tblVideos.reloadData()
     }
}
```